Can I restart the Cinnamon task switcher?
Ubuntu 22.04, Cinnamon DE 5.2.7.
The DE sometimes gets into a state where the task switcher (the thing that comes up when you Alt+Tab) starts somewhere in the middle instead of at the beginning.  It's a minor annoyance.
Is there a way to restart the Alt+Tab task switcher in Cinnamon without having to restart anything else?

Right click on the panel -> Troubleshoot -> Restart Cinnamon.
It should not affect any open programs.

Thanks, I just tried this.  The only thing it does is convert my Obsidian program icon into a place holder "blue gears" icon in the taskbar and in the task switcher.  The alt-tab switcher still starts in the middle.
